# Prompting for values to plug into a formula — how to do it elegantly

Tags: java, beginner

This is my first program in java. I am wondering if there would be a better way to tackle this. I am only allowed to use one class. It's not quite finished, but I am thinking it doesn't look very elegant.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CarHire
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        //customer details         
        System.out.println("Input customer's name: ");
        String name = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input customer's address: ");
        String address = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input customer's telephone: ");
        String telephone = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input customer's licence: ");
        String licence = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input customer's credit card number: ");
        String creditCard = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input customer's credit card expiry date: ");
        String cardExpiry = stdin.readLine();

    //days booked for hire
        System.out.println("Input number of days for hire: ");
        int daysBooked = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine());

        //car details
        System.out.println("Input make/model: ");
        String makeModel = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Input registration number: ");
        String regNumber = stdin.readLine(); 

        System.out.printf("%-20s %n %-40s %n","Select a car size:", "Small (S), Medium (M) or Large (L):");
        String carSize = stdin.readLine();

        //daily hire rate
        double dailyRate;

        if (carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("S") == true)
          {
            dailyRate=80;
          }
        else if (carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("M") == true)
          {
              dailyRate=110;
          }
        else
          {
              dailyRate=140;
          }

        //Calculate stage 1 hire
        double basicHire = dailyRate*daysBooked;

        System.out.printf("%-20s %15s %.2f %n %n", "Basic Hire is:", "$", basicHire);

        System.out.println("Number of days hired:");
        int daysHired = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());

        int lateDays = daysHired - daysBooked;
        double lateFee = 0;

        if (lateDays >0)
        {
            lateFee = dailyRate * 2 * lateDays;
        }
        //my test line
        double subTotal = basicHire + lateFee;
        System.out.printf("%-15s  %8.2f  %n %-15s %8.2f %n %-15s  %8.2f  %n",
                "Basic Hire: $", basicHire,  "Late Fee: $",  lateFee, 
                "Subtotal: $",  subTotal );

        String damage = null;
        String infringement = null;
        double repairCost = 0;
        double fines = 0;
        double repairCostTotal = 0;
        double finesTotal = 0;

        System.out.printf("%-30s %n %-30s %n %-30s %n","Damage? D", "Infringements? F", "Exit? X");
        String userInput = stdin.readLine();

        while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            System.out.println("Damage description:");
            damage = stdin.readLine();
            System.out.println("Repair Costs:");
            repairCost = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());
        }
        else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            System.out.println("Infringement type:");
            infringement = stdin.readLine();
            System.out.println("Fine:");
            fines = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());
        }
        else if (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("X")==true)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-30s %n %-30s %n %-30s %n %-30s %n",
                    "Enter a valid option:", "Damage? D", "Infringements? F", "Exit? X");
        }

        double finalHire  = lateFee + basicHire + repairCostTotal + finesTotal

    }
}
```

We have been told not to worry about data validation; with the exception of the enter D,F or X. And to use printf to format. It's an exercise to see if we can grasp the basics of java, using strings and nothing too fancy. We have been instructed which datatypes to use, for which variables.
So it is one of those restrictive programs, where there may be a better way to do it, that doesn't conform to what we have been asked. Nevertheless, I'm still keen to hear ideas. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given the constraints, your code looks mostly good. Ideally I would collect the user input in a loop instead of repating code for each entry. This may be out of scope for you at this point.
2. Your usage of `printf` is a bit contrived; again, it may be OK as practice.
3. One thing I'd definitely not leave is this line:

   ```
   while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
   ```

   Its subordinate clause is one huge if-else cascade: you should surround it with braces to make that clearer.
4. Still on the while-loop: you must involve `userInput=stdin.readLine()` within the loop. As you have it now, you read the command from the user only once, so it will be either an endless loop or never executed. The most convenient way could be a `while (true)`, then print the prompt, read it, and have another `else if` for the `X` case, which does a `break`.
5. Remove  `==true` from `!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("X")==true`. This just confuses the logic.

Comment: In fact, you'll need to change the logic with that while-loop because at the moment you never reassign to `userInput`. You must involve `userInput = stdin.readLine();` as a part of the loop. I'll add some more text to the answer...

Comment: Love your edit.. yes.. I knew there was something unhappy in my while.. and yes. already got rid of the ==true.. man tysm I appreciate it.. you wouldn't have a do while? As it needs to loop through it at least once anyway

Comment: You have nothing useful to put into the `while` condition because the decision to break out happens in the middle of loop code: after printing the prompt, but before the logic specific to each choice. The choice between `do-while(true)` and `while(true)` is arbitrary, but the latter is more obvious and concise.

Answer (score 4):

Since you can only use this one class, the key to having better, more beautiful code is to encapsulate logic in reusable and well-named methods.  Below is a modified version of the code which follows some basic design principles, which I will explain piece by piece.  Also, you have a lot of variables that you declare and never use, but I left them there under the assumption that they were going to be used in a future release.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarHire {

    private static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Customer Details
        String name = getInput("customer's name");
        String address = getInput("customer's address");
        String telephone = getInput("customer's telephone");
        String license = getInput("customer's license");
        String creditCard = getInput("customer's credit card number");
        String cardExpiry = getInput("customer's credit card expiry date");

        //Days Booked for Hire
        int daysBooked = getIntegerInput("number of days for hire");

        //Car Details
        String makeModel = getInput("make/model");
        String regNumber = getInput("registration number");
        String carSize = getInput("car size");

        //Daily Hire Rate
        int dailyRate = 0;
        if(carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
            dailyRate = 80;
        }
        else if(carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {
            dailyRate = 110;
        }
        else if(carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
            dailyRate = 140;
        }
        else {
            //TODO - what will you do if this is invalid?
        }

        //Calculate Stage 1 Hire
        int basicHire = dailyRate * daysBooked;
        System.out.println("Basic Hire is: " + basicHire);

        int daysHired = getIntegerInput("number of days hired");

        int lateDays = daysHired - daysBooked;
        int lateFee = lateDays > 0 ? (2 * dailyRate * lateDays) : 0;

        //My Test Line
        int subTotal = basicHire + lateFee;

        double finalHire = processFinalHire(basicHire, lateFee);

        System.out.println("Final hire: " + finalHire);
    }

    private static double processFinalHire(double basicHire, double lateFee) {

        String input = "";

        String damage, infringement;
        double repairTotal = 0.0;
        double finesTotal = 0.0;

        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            input = getInput("(Damage = D, Infringements = F, Exit = X");
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                damage = getInput("damage description");
                repairTotal += getDoubleInput("repair costs");
            }
            else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
                infringement = getInput("infringement type");
                finesTotal += getDoubleInput("fine");
            }
            else if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
            }
        }

        return lateFee + basicHire + repairTotal + finesTotal;
    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        System.out.print("Input " + prompt + ": ");
        return STDIN.nextLine().trim();
    }

    private static int getIntegerInput(String prompt) {
        Integer returnValue = null;
        while(returnValue == null) {
            System.out.print("Input " + prompt + ": ");
            try {
                returnValue = Integer.parseInt(STDIN.nextLine().trim());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static double getDoubleInput(String prompt) {
        Double returnValue = null;
        while(returnValue == null) {
            String input = getInput(prompt);
            try {
                returnValue = Double.parseDouble(input);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Please input a valid decimal.");
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

So let's walk through it!

```
private static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I changed your `BufferedReader` to a `Scanner` in order to avoid your having to handle `IOException`s in its initialization (or ignore them by having that ugly `throws IOException` clause on your `main` method, haha).  This is just an easier API to use at this level.  I've also moved it to be a `private static final` field for the entire `CarHire` class.  This will allow it to be referenced from all of the methods we create from here on out.

```
//Customer Details
String name = getInput("customer's name");
String address = getInput("customer's address");
String telephone = getInput("customer's telephone");
String license = getInput("customer's license");
String creditCard = getInput("customer's credit card number");
String cardExpiry = getInput("customer's credit card expiry date");
```

Notice how much cleaner this is than having the constant pairs of `System.out.println()` and `stdin.readLine()`?  It's because any processing which is repeated over and over can usually be encapsulated in its own method.  This makes your code more readable and reusable.  Let's skip down to the `getInput()` method to see what that means.

```
private static String getInput(String prompt) {
    System.out.print("Input " + prompt + ": ");
    return STDIN.nextLine().trim();
}
```

This method will print your input prompt and then wait for the user to hit enter/return on STDIN, then return whatever was typed.  I've added a `.trim()` call on the result for convenience and cleaner input.  (To see why that's relevant, consider what happens if your user types in "s   " for your `carSize` variable.)  I also changed the `println()` to be `print()`, just because I think it's a more beautiful command-line interface when the prompt is on the same line as where the user types. Of course, that's very subjective and completely up to you.

```
//Days Booked for Hire
int daysBooked = getIntegerInput("number of days for hire");
```

Same thing here.  Since we're going to be getting multiple integers from the user, we may as well encapsulate the processing.

```
private static int getIntegerInput(String prompt) {
    Integer returnValue = null;
    while(returnValue == null) {
        String input = getInput(prompt);
        try {
            returnValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

So this method is a little more complicated because I've added input validation to it.  We want to make sure the user actually inputs an integer, otherwise our program will crash, right?  This method may be a little more advanced than where you're at, so you can just skip over all of this if you want to ignore it.  But it's a good reference point for when you start to learn it later.

Step-by-step through this method...

```
Integer returnValue = null;
```

You might wonder why I'm using an `Integer` here instead of an `int`, and how that could possibly work with the rest of the code (since I explicitly declare that I'm returning an `int` in the method signature).  Java has a handy little feature called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) which lets you switch pretty much at will between the [primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and its associated object wrapper.  In this example, an `int` is associated with the `Integer` object, so when I `return returnValue` (where `returnValue` is an `Integer` object), it will automatically be converted to an `int` to the caller since that's what I've declared as the return type.

Why would I bother going through all this hassle and trickery?  It's a good question.  The reason is that a primitive type can't be `null`.  An `int` defaults to `0`.  I want to have something good to check for in my `while` condition, and I can't really check against an `int` appropriately, since anything an `int` can hold is... well... a valid `int`!  By doing it this way, I always know that I haven't gotten valid input by checking that one variable, rather than setting a dummy (possibly valid) value like `-1` or making another needless `boolean`.

```
try {
    returnValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
}
```

This `try`/`catch` construction allows us to do some basic [exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).  Basically what's happening here is that `Integer.parseInt(input)` will try to force the `String input` into an `int`, which will then get autoboxed into our `Integer` variable.  If `input` *can't* be parsed as an `int` (i.e., if it's not a valid integer), then the `Integer.parseInt()` call will throw a `NumberFormatException`.  This will be immediately caught in our `catch` block, at which point we simply print the error message to the user and continue execution as normal.  Because we are still within our `while` loop, we will keep doing this until the user enters a valid integer.

```
int lateFee = lateDays > 0 ? (2 * dailyRate * lateDays) : 0;
```

This is a small modification which I just thought prettied up the code a little bit.  It just uses the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java) to shorten all the variable declaration and if/else assignments into one line.

I think everything else pretty much follows what I've already said, so that's about it!  Let me know if you have any questions about the code.

---

Below is another version which is a bit more advanced because it uses an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), and [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  I like this because it makes getting a valid car size from the user and retrieving a `dailyRate` from it much cleaner and ties all the data together nicely.  It also prevents me from having to make `getIntegerInput()`, `getDoubleInput()`, `getLongInput()`... etc., etc.  It may be a bit over-engineered for this particular example, but it was fun to make.  Figuring it all out is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarHire {

    private static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);

    private enum CarSize {
        SMALL   ("S", 80),
        MEDIUM  ("M", 110),
        LARGE   ("L", 140);

        private final String inputOption;
        private final int dailyRate;

        private CarSize(String inputOption, int dailyRate) {
            this.inputOption = inputOption;
            this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        }

        public int getDailyRate() {
            return dailyRate;
        }

        public static CarSize fromString(String input) {
            for(CarSize size : values()) {
                if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(size.inputOption)) {
                    return size;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Customer Details
        String name = getInput("customer's name");
        String address = getInput("customer's address");
        String telephone = getInput("customer's telephone");
        String license = getInput("customer's license");
        String creditCard = getInput("customer's credit card number");
        String cardExpiry = getInput("customer's credit card expiry date");

        //Days Booked for Hire
        int daysBooked = getNumericInput("number of days for hire", Integer.class);

        //Car Details
        String makeModel = getInput("make/model");
        String regNumber = getInput("registration number");
        CarSize carSize = getCarSize();

        //Daily Hire Rate
        int dailyRate = carSize.getDailyRate();

        //Calculate Stage 1 Hire
        int basicHire = dailyRate * daysBooked;
        System.out.println("Basic Hire is: " + basicHire);

        int daysHired = getNumericInput("number of days hired", Integer.class);

        int lateDays = daysHired - daysBooked;
        int lateFee = lateDays > 0 ? (2 * dailyRate * lateDays) : 0;

        //My Test Line
        int subTotal = basicHire + lateFee;

        double finalHire = processFinalHire(basicHire, lateFee);

        System.out.println("Final hire: " + finalHire);
    }

    private static double processFinalHire(double basicHire, double lateFee) {

        String input = "";

        String damage, infringement;
        double repairTotal = 0.0;
        double finesTotal = 0.0;

        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            input = getInput("(Damage = D, Infringements = F, Exit = X");
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                damage = getInput("damage description");
                repairTotal += getNumericInput("repair costs", Double.class);
            }
            else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
                infringement = getInput("infringement type");
                finesTotal += getNumericInput("fine", Double.class);
            }
            else if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
            }
        }

        return lateFee + basicHire + repairTotal + finesTotal;
    }

    private static String getInput(String prompt) {
        System.out.print("Input " + prompt + ": ");
        return STDIN.nextLine().trim();
    }

    private static CarSize getCarSize() {
        CarSize returnValue = null;
        while(returnValue == null) {
            returnValue = CarSize.fromString(getInput("car size (Small = S, Medium = M, Large = L)"));
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static <T> T getNumericInput(String prompt, Class<T> numberType) {

        T returnValue = null;
        Method valueOf = null;

        if(!Number.class.isAssignableFrom(numberType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type must be a subclass of Number");
        }
        else {
            try {
                valueOf = numberType.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            }
            catch (SecurityException e) {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number type must support valueOf(String)");
            }
        }

        while(returnValue == null) {
            try {
                returnValue = numberType.cast(valueOf.invoke(null, getInput(prompt)));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please input a valid number.");
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: @ThinksALot Sure thing!  :)  Good luck with your class.  Don't let them hold you back from learning too much, haha.

Comment: I like this answer. I would just suggest `switch (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(0)))` to make it obvious that all of the chained `if`s have something in common.

Comment: @200_success Yeah, I thought of that, but that's why in the advanced version I just went with the `enum`. :)  Makes it much cleaner, in my opinion, since the `dailyRate` is directly tied to the `CarSize`.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my code (as per the requirements for the assignment, which was very specific re; data validation, methods and packages used).

I ended up using a `do while loop`. My logic behind this, was that it has to be run at least once to end the program. I've also fixed the formatting.

I was only allowed to concatenate my strings; rather than use arrays or lists.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CarHire
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        //customer details         
        System.out.print("Input customer's name: ");
        String name = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input customer's address: ");
        String address = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input customer's telephone: ");
        String telephone = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input customer's licence: ");
        String licence = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("\n" + "Input customer's credit card number: ");
        String creditCard = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input customer's credit card expiry date: ");
        String cardExpiry = stdin.readLine();

        //days booked for hire
        System.out.print("\n" + "Input number of days for hire: ");
        int daysBooked = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine());

        //car details
        System.out.print("Input make/model: ");
        String makeModel = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("Input registration number: ");
        String regNumber = stdin.readLine();

        System.out.print("\n" + "Select a car size:  Small (S), Medium (M) or Large (L):");
        String carSize = stdin.readLine();

        //STAGE 2
        //daily hire rate
        double dailyRate;

        if (carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
          {
            dailyRate=80;
          }
        else if (carSize.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
          {
              dailyRate=110;
          }
        else
          {
              dailyRate=140;
          }

        //Calculate stage 1 hire (basic hire)
        double basicHire = dailyRate * daysBooked;

        System.out.print("Number of days hired:");
        int daysHired = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());


        //Calculate  hire (with late fee)
        int lateDays = daysHired - daysBooked;
        double lateFee = 0.00;

        if (lateDays > 0)
        {
            lateFee = dailyRate * 2 * lateDays;
        }

        //my test line
        double subTotal = basicHire + lateFee;

        String userInput, damages, infringements; 
        String damageSummary = "";
        String fineSummary = "";
        double repairs = 0;
        double fines = 0;
        double repairTotal = 0;
        double fineTotal = 0;
        double hireTotal = 0;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("\n" + "Damage and infringement inventory:" + "\n" + 
        "Damage: D" + "\n" + "Infringements: F" + "\n" + "Exit: X" + "\n" +
                    "Enter Selection:");
            userInput = stdin.readLine();
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
            {
                System.out.println("Damage description:" );
                damages = stdin.readLine();

                System.out.println("Repair Costs:");
                repairs = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

                damageSummary = damageSummary + "\n" + damages + " $" + repairs;

                repairTotal = repairTotal + repairs;
            }
            else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
            {                
                System.out.println("Infringement type:");
                infringements = stdin.readLine();

                System.out.println("Fine:");
                fines = Double.parseDouble(stdin.readLine());

                fineSummary = fineSummary + "\n" + infringements + " $" + fines;
                fineTotal = fineTotal + fines;
            }
        }
        while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("x"));

        //Customer details
        System.out.println("\n" + "Customer Details: " + "\n");
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Name: ", name);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Address: ", address);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Telephone:", telephone);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Driver's licence:", licence);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Credit card number:", creditCard);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Credit card expiry:", cardExpiry);

        //Car hire details
        System.out.println("\n" + "Car Hire Details: " + "\n");
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Make and Model:", makeModel);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Registration No:", regNumber);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Hire Length (days):", daysBooked);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Daily Hire Rate:", dailyRate);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %40s %n", "Basic Hire Charge:", basicHire);

        //Days Hired
        System.out.println("\n" + "Days Hired: " + "\n");
        System.out.printf("%-30s %30.2f %n", "Late Return Surcharge:", lateFee);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %30.2f %n", "Adjusted Hire Charge:", subTotal);

        //Damage Repair Details
        System.out.println("\n" + "Damage Repair Details:");
        System.out.print(damageSummary);
        System.out.printf("%n %-30s %30.2f %n", "Total Damages:", repairTotal);

        //Infringement details
        System.out.println("\n" + "Traffic Infringement Details:");
        System.out.print(fineSummary);
        System.out.printf("%n %-30s %30.2f %n", "Total Fines:", fineTotal);

        //Final Hire Charge
        hireTotal  = lateFee + basicHire + repairTotal + fineTotal;
        System.out.printf("%n %-30s %30.2f %n", "Final Hire Charge:", hireTotal);
    }
}
```

*Please feel free to offer feedback.*

Comment: It's kind of inconvenient that you have a doubled check for `"X"`. You could use `while (true)` and have a `else break;` after `if (..."x")`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have to show this menu, at least once. I cannot bypass this menu. You don't like the do while? and by double check, the else if not "X" was to validate the data, so it would loop back if not F, D or X ... we had to validate using a loop! It was an exercise on the course work we had learnt to date... so if If I did while true and if "x" break.. I'd still need a condition to prompt for more user input, if the data was not valid.. so would I really be saving a step??

Comment: No, there would be no more checks, there would just be one less: the one you now have in the `while` check.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik took out extra line. kept it as a `do`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik created another question to discuss merits of loops http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31893/differences-between-using-a-do-while-and-a-while-and-initializing-variables

Comment: `do - while(true)` and `while(true)` are semantically identical, but the latter is more obvious because you see the loop condition at the top.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you write this into an answer.. it would be helpful.. I am not trying to be a dick.. just trying to understand ;) an answer to the new question

Comment: But it doesn't apply to your new question because it works only for the specific case `while (true)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik huh? the new question is just a snippet of the old code.. it could include anything

Comment: You don't have `while (true)` there, but a real condition. In that case the equivalence disappears.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If you mean by "semantically identical" that both work the same way, then no, that's not the case.

Comment: @bobby `while (true)` and `do ... while (true)` do not work the same way? Explain.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: `while (false) {}` will never execute, `do {} while (false)` will execute once.

Comment: @Bobby Thanks for that lovely note, but it is clearly irrelevant. You seem to have just misunderstood my statement, which pertains to the particular condition which I have mentioned and no other (a point which I have reiterated several times in the above comments).